# Attaching more than one animation scenekit

Tags: ios, objective-c, scenekit, caanimation

I have a 3D model built in blender exported for each animation. I have loaded the mesh successfully and can attach each animation.

Is there a way to get SceneKit to interpolate between two animations when a second (or third) is attached to the same mesh? If not, would having two animations that use seperate bones on the same skeleton mean they could be attached at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SceneKit character's animation workflow is designed to blend animation clips from different files rather than within the same file containing different takes (so called multi-take mixing). Animations in SceneKit can be applied both sequentially and in parallel.

Use [CAAnimationGroup](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/121145) class for multiple asset/character animations to run them concurrently. For simple transform animations running simultaneously use `SCNAction.group([SCNAction])`.